Filebeat not receiving packets from replayed pcap file, but tcpdump is
I'm replaying a PCAP file containing UDP packets only using tcpreplay, from one server to another (same IP subnet). The destination MAC address and IP address have been changed to that of the receiving server using tcprewrite. When I did a tcpdump on the receiving server, I'm able to capture the replayed packets. However, when I tried to run Filebeat and listening on the (destination) IP and port, I'm not getting any packets. Filebeat is set up correctly, because I was able to capture packets previously from another sender (not tcpreplay). It just doesn't seem to be able to see the replayed packets.
These are jumbo packets, and the MTU of the network interfaces on both servers have been changed to 9000, and the pcap was re-written with --mtu=6000 (each packet was about 6000B or smaller).
How can tcpdump see the packets, but not Filebeat?

tcpdump captures packets before they arrive at firewalling and IP stack and will thus show packets which are discared by those because of firewall rules, wrong routes, mismatching destination IP or similar.

Firewall is disabled, and the destination IP of the packets are set to (one of) the IP of the receiving interface. Is there anything I can do to determine where the problem lies?

This could be a case of dealing with Martian packets. The kernel drops these packets if they fail the RPF check
You can either disable the RPF or modify the source IP address to pass the RPF check.
There are a lot of details in replaying packets into the network, and this post here explains them in great detail.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
